# Fancybox 2 is it Possible To Navigate From Within a Slide Using Links

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a gallery (rel="gallery) and I am using Fancybox 2 to navigate between the slides.

I would like to know how I can navigate the slideshow from within each slide using a custom links.

slide.html

```
<article class="slide">
    <nav>
      <a href="#slide0" class="prev">PREVIOUS</a> | <a href="slide1" class="next">NEXT</a>
    </nav>
    <img src="image.jpg">
</article>
```

js

```
$slide.find('.next').fancybox.next();
$slide.find('.prev').fancybox.prev();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(".fancybox-next").click(); // for next button
$(".fancybox-prev").click(); // for prev button
```

so if you have your own button you will do like :

```
$(".next").click(function(){
  $(".fancybox-next").click(); 
})
```

you can then hide native next & prev button `$(".fancybox-next").hide();`

Comment: Always try the easiest solution first :)